# Wordpress Max File Upload Problem

Tags: php

I have created a wordpress custom post type. I am using custom field template to create fields. I have created a file field to upload images. When I upload files then It work like a charm but only 20 files get uploaded and other files get ignored. I know Its a php configuration and I have override the configuration by putting a php.ini file on my server root. Here is what I have done in it.

```
max_file_uploads = 300
```

When I run this command to check the configuration values:

```
echo "max_file_uploads: " . ini_get('max_file_uploads');
```

Then in output I get 300. But still I am unable to upload more then 20files in a single post. Am I missing something?

P.S I have a shared server and the files I am uploading have max size upto 1.5KB

Comment: file size, execution time, memory limit - they all affect how php handles uploads. it's not just one setting you need to check/tweak.

Comment: Well the other two things you mentioned are not actually the reason. I have tried the same thing with file more then 300KB and got the same result.

Comment: Try to change the max script execution time in PHP, in most cases it is the sole problem. Normally it is 300 which is around 6 Minutes and thus increase the time to 3000

Comment: Max execution time does not influence the upload. If PHP < 5.2.12, `max_file_uploads` does not exist, you can set it but it won't matter. The limit there will probably be the default one (20).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check my comment on your question above. Consider having an upload helper like fileuploader. This way, every upload is a request so no limit is reached.

[Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) allows you to drag&drop files and select multiples files to upload (although they are sent one by one).

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, although mine was limited to 25. The issue was the default `suhosin.upload.max_uploads` setting was set to 25, and like PHP versions before 5.3.4, empty upload fields would count towards this total.

The solution was to override the default `suhosin.upload.max_uploads` setting *after* it is included in `php.ini`. Look for the line `extension="suhosin.so"` and make sure it is somewhere after that.